# Explaining verity index and document search limits

Tags: collections, coldfusion, indexing, limits, verity

As present, we currently have a CF8 standard edition server which have some limitations around verity indexing. 
According to [Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=vspider_07.html)

```
Verity Server has the following document search limits (limits are for all collections registered to Verity Server):

 - 10,000 documents for ColdFusion Developer Edition 
 - 125,000 documents for ColdFusion Standard Edition
 - 250,000 documents for ColdFusion Enterprise Edition
```

We have now reached a stage where the server wide number of documents indexed exceed 125k. However, the largest verity collection consists of about 25k documents(and this is expected to grow). Only  one collection is ever searched at a time. In my understanding, this means that I can still search an entire collection with no restrictions. Is this correct? Or does it mean that only documents that were indexed across all collection prior to reaching the limit are actually searchable?

We are considering moving to CF9 standard as a solution to this and to use the Solr solution which has no restrictions. The [coldfusionjedi](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/10/30/Some-basic-SolrVerity-Differences) highlights some differences between Verity and Solr. However, before we upgrade I am trying to gain a clearer understanding of this before we commit to an upgrade.

Can someone provide me a clear explanation as to what this means and how it actually affects verity searching and indexing?

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that only the first N (N being the limit for your edition) is searched.

Comment: @CF Jedi. Thanks Ray, who better to provide an answer. Do you mean the first N across all collections. For example, collection 1 already has 50K records, collection 2 has 50k. I now create collection 3 with 50k records. Does this mean that only 25k records from collection 3 are available during the search? Or, are records that are sequentially indexed only available for searching?.

Comment: Ugh - I can see now how my comment doesn't really clear things up. Unfortunately - I'm not quite sure now. :( Of course, you can test this. One of the ways to search in Verity is by key. I don't remember the exact syntax, maybe <key> matches X, but that would let you see if a later inserted item is showing up.